# Where do we get ftl files for alfresco OOTB rename action

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

As we know alfresco OOTB provides rename document and rename folder functionality.
If we take mouse over to the folder name, then rename action is getting visible.

I want to use similar thing on my workflow form, is there any way to use similar thing in my workflow form.

Please let me know where I can find that rename action related ftl files and related code.

Find attached image for more information, In that I have Highlighted rename action part.[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48949559/how-to-add-custom-action-on-workflow-form-in-alfresco-to-rename-document-name/48990574#48990574

Answer (score 2):

The rename button not provided in ftl, it's added dynamically in `documentlist-view-detailed.js`, you can find it by searching `tip.insitu-rename`